# How to add specific values in column?

Tags: pandas

How to add specific values. If the value in the column ,nazwisko' ends with 'a', then the value in the new column is 'female', otherwise 'male'?

Comment: Can you add more context and code that you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pandas.Series.str.slice` to slice substrings from each element in the Series or Index. You can use `pandas.DataFrame.loc` to access a group of rows and columns.

---

Assuming the name of your DataFrame is `df`, the following code will add a `new_column` to your DataFrame with `'female'` value if the value in the column `nazwisko` ends with `'a'` and `'male'` value if the value in the column `nazwisko` does not end with `'a'`:

```
df['new_column'] = 'male'
df.loc[df.nazwisko.str.slice(-1) == 'a', 'new_column'] = 'female'
```

Comment: Thank You for Your advice. I have used it. 
dataset['płeć'] = 'male'
dataset.loc[dataset.nazwisko.str.slice(-1) == 'a', 'płeć'] = 'female'

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
  import numpy as np
  df['gender'] = np.where(df['nazwisko'].str[-1:] == 'a', 'Female', 'Male')
```

Comment: Thank You, I have to use pandas in this moment, on my course. But I will remember your advice.